# How do I restrict a user from edit his/her own profile

Tags: 8

I have some custom fields added to the user profile. some of these fields are filled and synced autimatically from an LDAP account and others only admins can fill.
I want to keep these aditional fields on the profile page but don't want to let the user itself modify these.
how can I restrict a user from edit his/her own profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either hide them from the form on the Manage Form tab, or use a form alter hook to set `#access` to FALSE if they don't fit a certain role.

You can also try the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Comment: great! thanks... I just found [User protect] (https://www.drupal.org/project/userprotect) but it doesn't allow granular field permissions control.